# How to check if user is active?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I'm querying Active Directory from client server using Java.

My base DN is

```
CN=GGM-FOX-MANAGER,OU=ClaimRoles,OU=Groups,OU=ENT,DC=ad,DC=myhostname,dc=com
```

So I am trying to extract all user from the group mentioned above using this query

```
(objectClass=*)
```

that returns so many key and values.

For example:

```
displayName: GGM-FOX-MANAGER
member: CN=100,OU=Employees,OU=Shopping,DC=RB,DC=ad,DC=myhostname,dc=com;and more users separated by ;
objectClass: top;group
objectCategory: CN=Group,Cn=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=ad,DC=myhostname,dc=com
cn=GGM-FOX-MANAGER
distinguishedName=CN=GGM-FOX-MANAGER,OU=ClaimRoles,OU=Groups,OU=ENT,DC=ad,DC=myhostname,dc=com
etc
```

How can I write query to extract only members only, instead of getting above example data ? secondly, how can I know the status of member, whether its active or not using query ?

Using Java

Answer (score 0):

Whenever making an LDAP query, you can tell it which attributes you want it to return for each result. If you don't specify anything, it will give you everything. You can tell it to only return the `member` attribute.

To look up information for each member, you will have to loop through each value of the `member` attribute, which gives you the distinguished name (DN) of each member. Then you can bind to that user object and look at the attributes of that object.

If you want to know if the account is enabled, you want to look at the second bit of the [`userAccountControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-useraccountcontrol) attribute. In Java, you take the value of `userAccountControl` with `& 2`. If the result is `2`, then it is disabled. If the result is `0`, it is enabled. I'm not a Java developer, but you can find an example [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53483884/1202807).